# Examples on N-D arrays usage

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was surprised when I started learning numpy that there are N dimensional arrays. I'm a programmer and all I thought that nobody ever use more than 2D array. Actually I can't even think beyond a 2D array. I don't know how think about 3D, 4D, 5D arrays or more. I don't know where to use them.

Can you please give me examples of where 3D, 4D, 5D ... etc arrays are used? And if one used  `numpy.sum(array, axis=5)` for a 5D array would what happen?

Answer (score 1):

A few simple examples are:

- A `n x m` 2D array of `p`-vectors represented as an `n x m x p` 3D matrix, as might result from computing the gradient of an image
- A 3D grid of values, such as a volumetric texture
- These can even be combined in the case of a gradient of a volume in which case you get a 4D matrix
- Staying with the graphics paradigm, adding time adds an extra dimension, so a time-variant 3D gradient texture would be 5D

`numpy.sum(array, axis=5)` is not valid for a 5D-array (as axes are numbered starting at 0)

Answer (score 0):

Practical applications are hard to come up with but I can give you a simple example for 3D.

Imagine taking a 3D world (a game or simulation for example) and splitting it into equally sized cubes. Each cube could contain a specific value of some kind (a good example is temperature for climate modelling). The matrix can then be used for further operations (simple ones like calculating its Transpose, its Determinant etc...).

I recently had an assignment which involved modelling fluid dynamics in a 2D space. I could have easily extended it to work in 3D and this would have required me to use a 3D matrix instead.

You may wish to also further extend matrices to cater for time, which would make them 4D. In the end, it really boils down to the specific problem you are dealing with.

As an end note however, 2D matrices are still used for 3D graphics (You use a 4x4 augmented matrix).

Answer (score 0):

For example, a 3D array could be used to represent a movie, that is a 2D image that changes with time.
For a given time, the first two axes would give the coordinate of a pixel in the image, and the corresponding value would give the color of this pixel, or a grey scale level. The third axis would then represent time. For each time slot, you have a complete image.

In this example, numpy.sum(array, axis=2) would integrate the exposure in a given pixel. If you think about a film taken in low light conditions, you could think of doing something like that to be able to see anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many examples... The way you are trying to represent it is probably wrong, let's take a simple example:

- You have boxes and a box stores N items in it. You can store up to 100 items in each box.
- You've organized the boxes in shelves. A shelf allows you to store M boxes. You can identify each box by a index.
- All the shelves are in a warehouse with 3 floors. So you can identify any shelf using 3 numbers: the row, the column and the floor.

A box is then identified by: row, column, floor and the index in the shelf.

An item is identified by: row, column, floor, index in shelf, index in box.

Basically, one way (not the best one...) to model this problem would be to use a 5D array.

Answer (score 0):

They are very applicable in scientific computing. Right now, for instance, I am running simulations which output data in a 4D array: specifically

| Time | x-position | y-position | z-position |.

Almost every modern spatial simulation will use multidimensional arrays,  along with programming for computer games.